# Going over start of insert action in Z shell vi-mode

Tags: zsh, vi-mode

Is it possible to configure the vi-mode of the Z shell so that backspace can delete characters *before* the position where the insert action was started?

Basically the behavior of vim which can be achieved by adding the following line to `~/.vimrc`

```
set backspace=start
```

– is it possible to have this in Z shell vi-mode?

Comment: Possible? I'm not sure, but if nothing else, the source code is there. Note though that you're dealing with "vi-mode", not "vim-mode", so it is quite likely that several vim-exclusives are missing

Comment: @Fox if you know a patch, feel free to post it :-)

Comment: This doesn't require a patch. Even if it can't be done with configuration, it can be done by defining a function that does the job and binding it to backspace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add this to your zsh configuration:

```
bindkey -M viins '^?' backward-delete-char
bindkey -M viins '^H' backward-delete-char
```

#### Explanation:

*Vi-mode* is just a set of preconfigured keymaps (*viins*, *vicmd*, *viopp*, *visual*) that bind certain keys to certain widgets. Some of these widgets are specifically designed to behave close to the way the *vi* editor does.

In your case this is the `vi-backward-delete-char` widget that is by default bound to <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in the *viins* mode, which has the specific feature to not delete past the position where insert mode was entered.

Often sligthtly different versions of these widgeds exist, that behave more in line with the *emacs* editor. In this case it would be the `backward-delete-char` widget, which is not limited to the current insert session. Although it is by default bound in *emacs-mode*, there are no hard restrictions on which widget can be used in which mode. You can use `backward-delete-char` within *vi-mode* by simply rebinding <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to call the widget `backward-delete-char` instead.

The reason for there being two bindings - `^?` and `^H` - is that it depends on the terminal, which of those two key sequences is sent on pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. By default both are bound to the same widget in *vi-mode* as well as *emacs-mode*.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure this one out. Thanks!